# Retrieve value from an Array in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to get some data to display from an Array in Cakephp, the Array has all the data from a find() output and other parts of the data output fine.

The data i am trying to access is the name field inside company , the code i am using is `echo $quote['Company']['name']` but it returns and error saying that the index is undefined. The code `echo $quote['Status']['name']` works fine

The contents of the array looks like this

```
    Array ( 
[Quote] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Eighties Yeh that aint right [revision] => 1 [status_id] => 1 [contact_id] => 1 [totalcost] => 500 [created] => 2010-01-20 13:26:36 ) [Status] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Open 
[Quote] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Eighties Yeh that aint right [revision] => 1 [status_id] => 1 [contact_id] => 1 [totalcost] => 500 [created] => 2010-01-20 13:26:36 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Eighties Yeh that aint right [revision] => 1 [status_id] => 1 [contact_id] => 1 [totalcost] => 500 [created] => 2010-01-20 13:26:36 ) 

[1] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => Test [revision] => 12 [status_id] => 1 [contact_id] => 1 [totalcost] => 23 [created] => 2010-01-20 19:05:36 ) ) ) 
[Contact] => Array ( [id] => 1 [company_id] => 1 [name] => Kieran Hutchinson [email] => kieran@redmeetsblue.com.au 
[Company] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Red Meets Blue ) 
[Quote] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Test Quote 2 [revision] => 1 [status_id] => 0 [contact_id] => 1 [totalcost] => 300 [created] => 2010-01-17 10:30:31 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Test Quote 2 [revision] => 1 [status_id] => 0 [contact_id] => 1 [totalcost] => 300 [created] => 2010-01-17 10:30:31 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 5 [name] => test 4 [revision] => 1 [status_id] => 3 [contact_id] => 1 [totalcost] => 233 [created] => 2010-01-20 19:05:55 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Eighties Yeh that aint right [revision] => 1 [status_id] => 1 [contact_id] => 1 [totalcost] => 500 [created] => 2010-01-20 13:26:36 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => Test [revision] => 12 [status_id] => 1 [contact_id] => 1 [totalcost] => 23 [created] => 2010-01-20 19:05:36 ) 
[4] => Array ( [id] => 6 [name] => Test Lost Quote [revision] => 1 [status_id] => 4 [contact_id] => 1 [totalcost] => 123 [created] => 2010-01-21 16:00:43 ) 
[5] => Array ( [id] => 7 [name] => Test Pending QUote [revision] => 1 [status_id] => 2 [contact_id] => 1 [totalcost] => 321 [created] => 2010-01-21 16:00:57 ) ) ) [QuoteItem] => Array ( ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your array, it would seem you need to access it via `$quote['Contact']['Company']['name']`